# How to convert a HTML string to an image in Android AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, webview

is there anybody know how to convert a HTML page to an image in Android AsyncTask or background thread?

Environment: Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5, Android Tablets with API version 18, 19

I have tried WebView control with two solutions but all failed.

- Solution 1: Javascript

It doesn't work, getDrawingCache(true) always returns null.

```
public void generateImage()
{
    final WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(150);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(mWebView), "Android");

    String html = "<html><body onload=\"Android.captureImage()\">hello world<p>bbb</p></body></html>";
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
}

public class JavaScriptInterface 
{
    private WebView mWebView;

    public JavaScriptInterface(WebView webView) {
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void captureImage()
    {
        Bitmap b = mWebView.getDrawingCache(true);
        if(b==null){
            System.out.println("... b is null");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("... height "+b.getHeight()+"    width "+b.getWidth());
    }
}
```

- Solution 2: WebViewClient + PictureListener

This one works on Android API 19. But on Android API 18, the callback "onNewPicture" is never get called.

```
public void generateImage()
{
    final WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(150);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    String html = "<html><body>hello world<p>bbb</p></body></html>";
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("............ onPageFinished");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.clearCache(true);
        }
    });

    mWebView.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture)
        {
            if (picture == null) {
                return;
            }

            Picture pic = mWebView.capturePicture();
            if(pic==null){
                System.out.println("............ pic is null");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("onNewPicture............ width ["+pic.getWidth()+"]  hieght ["+pic.getHeight()+"]");
            final Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
            canvas.drawPicture(pic);
        }
    });
}
```

I can get image if I create WebView control in following way

```
final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

But I have to convert the html page string in an AsyncTask or a background thread. there is no UI at all. Is there anybody know how to implement it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can always call the onDraw of the webview, passing it in a Canvas that draws to a Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

first set layout parameter for your `WebView`, second you should call `Webview.measure` and `WebView.layout` methods then draw cache on a bitmap:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i("HTML", "page finished loading " + url); 
                view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(512, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
                final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
                canvas.drawBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, new Paint());
                // bitmap is ready
            }
);
```

**IMPORTANT TIP**: make sure your `WebView` height and width isn't zero.